# Using JSLint with Syntastic in Vim

Tags: vim

I'm using [Syntastic](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2736) for syntax checking in Vim - whenever I save an `.rb` file, it runs it through a syntax checker and highlights errors for me. Spiffy. Same for several other file types: HAML, HTML, etc. It does this by calling out to external syntax checkers and displaying the errors they return.

Syntastic can be configured various ways, but this is what I added to my `.vimrc`:

```
  " When writing a file, if there are errors, have Syntastic plugin mark them
  let g:syntastic_enable_signs=1
  let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list=1
```

Lately, I've had several elusive Javascript bugs that I eventually found by copying and pasting my code into the [web interface of JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/). I'd really like to have JSLint run on my `.js` files every time I save them, but searching for "command line JSLint" has mostly gotten me confusion.

Is there an official command-line version of JSLint? Does anybody have clear instructions on getting JSLint to run via Syntastic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Syntastic is looking for the `jsl` binary in your path.  You can download jsl (command line js lint) from http://www.javascriptlint.com/download.htm

After it is installed I would restart vim and viola, it should work.

If you are on a mac, you can also do `brew install jslint` and it will install the jsl executable for you.

Comment: After using brew i had to add to my .vimrc this

    let g:syntastic_javascript_checkers = ['jslint']

Answer (score 9):

As noted by Adam the `jsl` binary is the easiest way to get things set up.  I'd like to note, however, that you can also install a `jslint` in your path via npm (so long as you already have npm and node.js installed):

`npm install -g jslint`

The -g flag tells npm you want to install the package globally.

Comment: You can also use `jshint` if you like. `npm install -g jshint`